# I would like to display Xcode on Discord

Tags: xcode, discord

https://github.com/AsadAzam/DiscordX

I want the files I edit in Xcode to appear in Discord just like Visual Studio Code.
So I found the following DiscordX.

I'm using Xcode 12 and I'm getting the following error:

> the Swift tools version specification is missing a label; consider inserting 'swift-tools-version:' between the comment marker and the version specifier

> /Users/(USERNAME)/Documents/Xcode/DiscordX/DiscordX.xcodeproj Missing package product 'SwordRPC'

> Resolving Package Graph Failed

I'm not sure how to use Xcode. I tried installing something called cocoapods, but the same error repeats.

Comment: You might want to use [RPFX](https://github.com/PKBeam/RPFX). Btw, are you using the zip file of Xdiscord in the issues section of the repository?

Comment: Ah misread DiscordX as [XDiscord](https://github.com/jariz/XDiscord), which is what I've been using

Comment: I don't care about XDiscord, DiscordX, RPFX either. Could you tell me how?

Comment: I don't know about the error, but I can build it and upload the compiled app to the repo. Are you using a M1 or Intel mac?

Comment: I'm using M1 MacBook Air.

Comment: Interesting, getting the same error.

Comment: Well how to build it?

Comment: Idk. I suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/AsadAzam/DiscordX/issues) in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Xcode 13.1, this issue get fixed after applying File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches enjoy